# How to prove that the Haar system is orthonormal?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

[Haar wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) are defined as:

$$
\psi_{0,0}(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ for } 0<t< 1/2\\
-1, \text{ for } 1/2<t<1 \\
0, \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Where mother wavelet is$$\psi_{n,k} = 2^{-n/2} \psi_{0,0}(2^n t -k).$$
And for $n \geq 0$, $0 \leq k < 2^n$
$$
{\psi_{i,n}\psi_{k,l}}  = \delta_{i,l}\delta_{k,n}$$

Show that these wavelets form an orthonormal set:

Comment: Any book on wavelet theory has a proof. If there are some steps in the proof that you don't understand we will try to help you.

Comment: apologies for my editing mistake previously, but I couldn't  find a proof related to my query.

Comment: Go to statmathbc.wordpress.com, click on Catalog, click on Basic Wavelet Theory and then click on Haarlets. You can download my notes on wavelets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show the following $$\langle \psi_{n,k_1},\psi_{n,k_2}\rangle=0\\\langle \psi_{n_1,k},\psi_{n_2,k}\rangle=0\\\langle \psi_{n_1,k_1},\psi_{n_2,k_2}\rangle=0\\\langle \psi_{n,k},\psi_{n,k}\rangle=1$$when $n_1\ne n_2$ and $k_1\ne k_2$ and $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_Df(x)g^*(x)dx$$

**(1)** for $k_1\ne k_2$

$$\langle \psi_{n,k_1},\psi_{n,k_2}\rangle{=\int_{\Bbb R}2^{-n}\psi_{0,0}(2^nx-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(2^nx-k_2)dx\\=2^{-2n}\int_{\Bbb R}\psi_{0,0}(u-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(u-k_2)du\\=2^{-2n}\int_{(k_1,k_1+1)\cap(k_2,k_2+1)}\psi_{0,0}(u-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(u-k_2)du\\=2^{-2n}\int_{\emptyset}\psi_{0,0}(u-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(u-k_2)du\\=0}$$

**(2)** for $n_1\ne n_2$ withput loss of generality assume $n_1>n_2$. Therefore$$\langle \psi_{n_1,k},\psi_{n_2,k}\rangle{=\int_{\Bbb R}2^{-{n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x-k)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x-k)dx\\=\int_{({k\over 2^{n_1}},{k+1\over 2^{n_1}})\cap ({k\over 2^{n_2}},{k+1\over 2^{n_2}})}2^{-{n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x-k)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x-k)dx}$$note that for $k\ne 0$ $${k+1\over 2^{n_1}}\le {k\over 2^{n_2}}$$and therefore $$({k\over 2^{n_1}},{k+1\over 2^{n_1}})\cap ({k\over 2^{n_2}},{k+1\over 2^{n_2}})= \emptyset$$This important result says that $\langle \psi_{n_1,k},\psi_{n_2,k}\rangle= 0$ whenever $k\ne 0$. In the case $k=0$ we obtain $$\langle \psi_{n_1,0},\psi_{n_2,0}\rangle{=\int_{(0,{1\over 2^{n_1}})\cap (0,{1\over 2^{n_2}})}2^{-{n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x)dx\\=\int_0^{1\over 2^{n_1}}2^{-{n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x)dx\\=\int_0^{1}2^{-{3n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(u)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u)du\\=\int_0^{1}2^{-{3n_1+n_2\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(u)du=0}$$

**(3)**

We show that $$\int_{\Bbb R}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x-k_2)dx=0$$

*proof*

Assume $n_2>n_1$. Therefore

$$\int_{\Bbb R}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_1}x-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2}x-k_2)dx{={1\over 2^{n_1}}\int_{k_1}^{k_1+1}\psi_{0,0}(u-k_1)\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u-k_2)du}\\={1\over 2^{n_1}}\int_{k_1}^{k_1+{1\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u-k_2)du-{1\over 2^{n_1}}\int_{k_1+{1\over 2}}^{k_1+1}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u-k_2)du$$from the other side $${1\over 2^{n_1}}\int_{k_1}^{k_1+{1\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u-k_2)du=0$$ since $${1\over 2^{n_1}}\int_{k_1}^{k_1+{1\over 2}}\psi_{0,0}(2^{n_2-n_1}u-k_2)du{={1\over 2^{n_2}}\int_{k_1\cdot 2^{n_2-n_1}}^{\left(k_1+{1\over 2}\right)\cdot 2^{n_2-n_1}}\psi_{0,0}(w-k_2)dw\\={1\over 2^{n_2}}\int_{k_1\cdot 2^{n_2-n_1}-k_2}^{\left(k_1+{1\over 2}\right)\cdot 2^{n_2-n_1}-k_2}\psi_{0,0}(w)dw\\=0}$$where the last equality comes from $$\int_0^1 \psi_{0,0}(x)dx=0$$

**(4)**

$$\langle \psi_{n,k},\psi_{n,k}\rangle{=\int_{\Bbb R}2^{-n}\psi_{0,0}^2(2^nx-k)dx\\=\int_{k\over 2^n}^{k+1\over 2^n}2^{-n}\psi_{0,0}^2(2^nx-k)dx\\=\int_{k\over 2^n}^{k+1\over 2^n}2^{-n}dx\\=1}$$which finishes our (long and exhaustive!) proof $\blacksquare$

Comment: In (3), $\frac{1}{2^{n_2}} \int^{(k_1+\frac{1}{2})2^{n_2 - n_1} + k_2}_{k_1 2^{n_2-n_1}+k_2}$ should be $\frac{1}{2^{n_2}} \int^{(k_1+\frac{1}{2})2^{n_2 - n_1} - k_2}_{k_1 2^{n_2-n_1}-k_2}$

Comment: Thanks. Got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the supports are disjoint then of course the $L^2$ inner product is zero. If the supports overlap, the explanation for the orthogonality is as follows. A Haar wavelet has zero integral, or averages to zero. The wavelet with higher frequency (higher $n$) has support in an interval where the lower frequency wavelet is constant. So the inner product is just that constant times the spatial average of the  higher frequency wavelet, i.e., zero.